# When I take the derivative of a function, do I also take the derivative of the denominator?

Tags: derivatives

I'm in grade 12 Calculus at the moment and I have a pretty simple question.

Imagine the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$. If I were to take the derivative, by the power law, the numerator would become $1$. However, if I took the derivative of this function, would I also apply the power law to the denominator? If I did, then the denominator would become 0 and the function would be undefined (assuming $x\neq 0$).

Is this correct, or do I only take the derivative of the numerator and let the answer be $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Look up the Quotient rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac{x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}x$. Using the power rule, we can take the derivative of $f(x)$ as follows. $$\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{1}{2}x]=\frac{1}{2}$$

Your derivative is indeed $\frac{1}{2}$, however, you have to be careful with taking the derivative of the numerator whenever you are differentiating a quotient. When you have a rational function, say $f(x)=\frac{2x+6}{6x^2+1}$ you need something called the quotient rule.

If I understand what you are asking, it seems that you haven't learned about the quotient rule yet. The quotient rule is a general method of differentiating quotients and it will work for your function, although it would just be easier to rewrite the function as I did.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The quotient rule says

$$\frac d{dx} \frac x2 = \frac{2\frac{d}{dx}x - x\frac d{dx} 2}{2^2} = \frac{2-0}{2^2} = \frac 12$$